# How to count instances of metric values t(now) vs t(1m) with condition in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a **gauge** metric that is getting temperature per minute. I use the following query to check change in temperature value now vs 1min ago.

```
temperature - temperature offset 1m
```

I can see the result on timeline as:
[image]

I want to calculate the **number of times**, let's say in 1 hour that the value of change in temperature was more than 5. In this case, it would total to 1 as can be seen from timeline.

I tried the following, but always get **Empty query result**

```
(temperature - temperature offset 1m) > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should return the number of times the `temperature` changed by more than 5 during a minute over the last hour:

```
count_over_time(
  ((temperature - temperature offset 1m) > 5)[1m:1h]
)
```

It uses [count_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_over_time) function and [subquery feature](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/).

Note that the `temperature` may change by more than 5 degrees in both directions (e.g. it may increase or decrease). The query above counts only temperature increases. If you need counting also temperature decreases by more than 5 degrees, then the following query should work:

```
count_over_time(
  (abs(temperature - temperature offset 1m) > 5)[1m:1h]
)
```

It additionally uses [abs() function](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#abs).